# laravel 419 (unknown status)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, token

7 project and VueJs2 
This is my VueJs2 code

```
mounted: function() {
   if(this.edit != null)
   {
        var token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
        console.log(token);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: path+'get_voucher_data',
            data: [{'_token':token}],
            success:(data) => {
                console.log(data);
             }
        });
   }
}
```

but I have this error: 
[image]

```
POST http://localhost/test/public/get_voucher_data 419 (unknown status)
```

Also, this is my blade code:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Does anyone know why this happens, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laravel has a middleware called `VerifyCsrfToken` which is enabled by default. It makes sure all POST requests have a csrf token. This tokens make sure the request is sent from our app only and not from any 3rd party **scraper** or form submiting tool.

When controller does not get _token in request, it throws error.

It seems like you are trying to send but not corectly. Update to this :

```
var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

data: {
   _token : token 
},
```

Currently you following which is not sending token correctly :

```
data: [{'_token':token}]
```

**Easier configuration :**

Instead of sending _token in every ajax request, you can setup the jquery ajax :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: {
        _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Then every ajax request will automatically have this, no need to specify it again in every ajax request data.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your token on the header:

```
headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
},
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also send the token in the body. Make sure you send it as json, JSON.stringify the body and also add the content-type to the header.

```
fetch("/route-to-post", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        _token: token
    })
})
```